# android export failing in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

When I try to export my Android application in eclipse I hust get this error

> [2011-11-10 17:52:51 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/myDomain/MyProjectthatIcan'texport/R$array;

I only get this when I try and export the project to APK, not when I build and the project doesn't have any errors

How do I solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way of solving this... You use the Android AVD to delete your AVDs (Android virtual devices), you use the SDK manager to delete the downloaded SDKs, then you use your file explorer to delete the folder which has the SDK things in, and you delete eclipse. You then reinstall eclipse and the android SDKs and try the export again; it worked for me.
**NB Do not delete your workspace!!!**

Answer (score 0):

try this first by disabling the automatic build feature.."Project->Build Automatically" option, then "Clean" and "Build" your project. This should fix it. If not you can try deleting the bin dir for your project and re-execute the above steps and then run it.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I've tried this and still get the same error message - any other ideas?